# ways of forming a timetable for trains

Tags: combinatorics

> A train timetable must be compiled for various days of the week so that two trains twice a day depart for three days, one train daily for two days,and three trains once a day for two days. How many different timetables can be compiled

What I tried:

Let two trains which run twice  a days depart  for $3$ days   mapped as $A_{1},A_{2}$

and  one train departs  daily for two days mapped as $B$

and three trains  departs once a day for two days mapped as $C_{1},C_{2},C_{3}$

i am trying to form a table for running trains but did not understand how to form it

help me please

Comment: what do you mean by "two trains twice a day depart for three days, one train daily for two days". Why put the word **daily** next to the phrase **for two days** and no connection word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is worded a little confusingly, but this is what I'm getting:

There should be three days of the week where exactly four trains leave, two at a time.

There should be two days of the week where exactly one train leaves.

There should be two days of the week where exactly three trains leave, all at one time.

Assuming that no two trains are distinct, encode the 3 four-train days as $"A"$, encode the 2 one-train days as $"B"$, and encode the 2 three-train days as $"C"$. Then the problem just becomes how many distinct orderings are there of $"AAABBCC"$, which should be:
$$\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} = \frac{7!}{3!2!2!} = 210.$$

If the trains are all distinct, then we just have to account for reordering the trains within this schedule, so we would then multiply by the groupings in which they can leave. The total number of trains will be $4*3+1*2+3*2 = 20$, so the number of ways the trains can be grouped into departures is: $$\binom{20}{2}\binom{18}{2}\binom{16}{2}\binom{14}{2}\binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{3}*2*1 = \frac{20!}{(2!)^6(3!)^2} = 1.0559470522×10^{15}.$$
So if all the trains are distinct, then the total number of ways of scheduling them on this timetable would be:
$$[\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}][\binom{20}{2}\binom{18}{2}\binom{16}{2}\binom{14}{2}\binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{3}*2*1]=\frac{(20!)(7!)}{(2!)^8(3!)^3}.$$
If for whatever reason the numerical answer is needed, it's $2.2174888095×10^{17}.$